# windows 8.1 pro config\systemprofile\desktop

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I changed the properties of my systemprofile folder - I tried to add my own name as a user with full rights (even though I am the administrator), but now I have lost the file "C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\desk top" (it is no longer visible)and I am getting the error message "shellexecuteEX failed to start:code1068 the dependency service or group failed to start. Most applications will not open and my desktop shows only a couple of icons (even they all show when I open my computer and click on the desktop folder).

I eventually managed to boot into safe mode with a command prompt allowing ne to run sfc /scannow but resulted in a message "Windows resource protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log. windir\logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs. Note that logging is currently not supported in offline servicing Scenarios.

Internet Explorer will not start but SAS can automatically update its database over the internet.
 All shares are accessible from other computers. Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Try a System Restore to a point before you made the change.

Answer (score 0):

Try next `.bat` script:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions
set "common=Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer"
call :query "HKU\.DEFAULT\Software\%common%\User Shell Folders" "Desktop"
call :query "HKCU\Software\%common%\Shell Folders" "Desktop"
call :query "HKCU\Software\%common%\User Shell Folders" "Desktop"
call :query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\%common%\Shell Folders" "Common Desktop"
call :query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\%common%\User Shell Folders" "Common Desktop"
call :query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\%common%\Shell Folders" "Common Desktop"
call :query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\%common%\User Shell Folders" "Common Desktop"
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:query
reg query "%~1" /V "%~2"|findstr "REG_"
goto :eof
```

Output should be as follows (except last two `Wow6432Node` items on 32 bit OS):

```
==>D:\bat\SU\935604.bat
    Desktop           REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
    Desktop           REG_SZ           C:\Users\<CurrentUserName>\Desktop
    Desktop           REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
    Common Desktop    REG_SZ           C:\Users\Public\Desktop
    Common Desktop    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %PUBLIC%\Desktop
    Common Desktop    REG_SZ           C:\Users\Public\Desktop
    Common Desktop    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %PUBLIC%\Desktop
```

I will delete this answer ASAP if it will not help.